# Inode Table and blocks

Tags: linux, file, block, inode

I have a problem that I want to resolve :

Text: 
 We are in EXT2 with blocks of 1024 bytes. How many inodes can we put in a block?
We have 13 files on FS, how many blocks are in the inode table?

REsults :
 .

A inode is 128 bytes , so 1024/128 =8 
so we can put 8 inodes in each block.

But I don't have any idea for the number of blocks in inode table.

I try that : 
We have 13 files , so simple indirection : so 12 + 1024/4 = 268 blocks?

Someone can help me please?

Comment: This would be better suited for research on places like https://unix.stackexchange.com/ i.e., do your research over there and if you still have a question craft one that fits those recommendations.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i didn't find any answer about my problem.. So i asked there

Comment: What's the practical issue behind this, or what's the source of the question? Is it homework?

Comment: Yes you right , it's for a test. But i don't know , how many blocks can be in the inode table..

Comment: That was to be expected since the premise of the question is somewhat off in some practical details. The number of inodes on an ext2 fs are set when the fs is created, usually as a function of the file system size, but it can be anything. It's _not_ a function of the number of files currently on the filesystem, so there's not enough information to answer the question. (Then there's the minor detail that there's actually an inode table for each block group on the fs, but we could call that a naming issue.)

Comment: Frankly, I don't suppose any of that is the expected answer, but that's tests for you. But since we only know the number of files, we could figure out how many inodes there must be at minimum? How many blocks will storing them require?